# ScrollView Does not Scrolll Smoothly

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I am adding a `ScrollView` and several `TextView` together. I am populating data using a web service (php/mysql data from server). Everything is fine except one issue. When user scrolls the page/activity, the scroll is not as smooth as a `listview`.

I am posting my xml here:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrolFullText"
    tools:context=".FullText" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HEAD"
        android:text="@string/HEAD"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"   
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
    />

     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/WRITER"
     android:text="@string/WRITER"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="18sp"   
     android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
    />    


          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CATEGORY"
        android:text="@string/CATEGORY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
         />   


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT"
        android:text="@string/TEXT"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
         />   

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I make my scroll a little smoother?

Comment: Could you post your adapter code? It could be something to do how you populate your scrollview

Comment: I am just using an AyncTask and setting my text using `textview.setText(DataFromServer)`;

Answer (score 0):

The scroll may be not smooth because some background job is being processed, you may test your app on multiple devices.

By the way I guess the `ScrollView` height should be `match_parent`